# Raw images usage and technical explanation?

Tags: canon, canon-600d

How to take RAW images in Canon 600D ?
What is the use of making RAW than jpg ?
Does the quality differs or the we can edit easily ?

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2627/15871

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5410/why-can-i-adjust-the-white-balance-of-a-raw-file-but-not-a-jpeg-file

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-when-shooting-in-raw-vs-jpeg/28#28

Comment: Thanks @MichaelClark this gives me more curious to take pictures using RAW format. After editing raw images can we save it into jpeg or RAW always.

Comment: You can save it as a jpeg. In fact, what you see on your screen when working with RAW files isn't really the RAW file itself, rather it is a conversion of the RAW file to a format very much like jpeg. Many applications can't display RAW files, so you need to save it as a jpeg, tiff, or png, etc. The point of working with RAW files is to allow you to make your choices regarding white balance, exposure, contrast, tone curves, etc. for that specific image BEFORE you bake all those decisions in by converting to jpeg and throwing away the information in the RAW file you didn't need or use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To shoot RAW images, you can just set your camera to RAW (or RAW+JPG) in the image quality settings. The reason to shoot RAW is, like you stated, to edit later on. Because of the way a RAW file is build up and the information it contains (compared to JPG), editing can be done better and far more extensively than jpg.

Comment: cant we edit better using JPEG ?